# Scraping email address from html page using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to find email addresses from the HTML file, I need email addresses with top-level domain(tld) to level 1 only, for example from the email addresses given below, bold addresses are invalid in this case

- test@domain12.com
- test@domain12.com
- test123@domain-12.com
- **test@domain.co.au**
- **test.abc@domain.ac.nz**
- test@abc.co
- example@testdomain.net
- sample@organization.org

I am using the following regex it works fine if there are only email addresses, but if I add any text after the email addresses it doesn't match the criteria.

(?=<\s|^)\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$(?=\s|$|.+)

**success case:**

- test@domain12.com
- example@testdomain.net
- sample@organization.org

**Failure case:**

- test@domain12.com random text after email address
- example@testdomain.net random text after email address
- sample@organization.org random text after email address

Any help in this scenario will be really appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Remove dollar sign from the end od regex. And dont forget, that tld can be more than 6 chars length.

Comment: This solution consider tlds up to two level, where I need tld to one level only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this regex:

```
(?<=\s|^)([a-z0-9-.])+@+([a-z0-9-]*)\.([a-z]*)\s
```

It extracts email from string with one level tld. You can tokenize the text on spaces/line breaks and iteratively match with regex.

[follow this link](https://regex101.com/r/0MomFg/2)

Answer (score 0):

I've made the regex - my custom validator to extract the email addresses like that.

Try this:

```
^(?<check_Duplicate_Special_Symbol>(?![\w-.]*[\.@][\.@][\w-]*))(?<user>(?!\.)[\w.-]+)(?<domain>@(?:[A-Za-z][\w-.]*))(?<subDomain>(?:\.[A-Za-z][\w-.]*)+)$
```

For more info see [regex-demo](https://regexr.com/5h1ac)

But, it is not a good choice. You could consider [how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) to get a correctly validator.

Answer (score 0):

Try This for a single match:

```
(?:\s)(.[^@]*@[^.]*\.[^.0-9A-Z]*)(?:\s)
```

or This for a top level match and a match per-section:

```
(?:\s)((.[^@])(?:*@)([^.]*)(?:\.)([^.0-9A-Z]*))(?:\s)
```